# Getting an error for the features.h header, even though I haven't touched it?

Tags: c, compilation

I am running Linux Mint. When I try to compile a program in C using gpp from command line, I get this output, and my program does not compile.

```
$ gpp snake.cpp -o snake
features.h:384: warning: Extra argument to #endif ignored
features.h:396: error: #define/#defeval requires an identifier or a single macro call
```

I'm not sure why I would ever be getting an error for a standard library that I haven't even touched.

Comment: Don't know. Are you able to compile a simple "Hello, world" program?

Comment: I am unable to compile anything including stdio.h or stdlib.h

Comment: That means the compiler hasn't been installed correctly. You may have missed a step...